# Can I have an electron build run without the localhost in the background?

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I am able to get my electron build working while I have my React build running from my `http://localhost:3000`. However, it only works when I have the localhost up.

I am quite new with electron, and it might not even be the utility I'm looking for. Is there a way to have my electron build run without the localhost running in the back?

My goal is to package my React App and run it on other devices via an executable file without having to run a server or coding software.

Currently I have:

package.json

```
{
  "homepage": "./",
  "main": "./public/main.js",
  "build": {
    "appId": "test",
    "compression": "normal",
    "asar": true,
    "extends": null,
    "files": [
      "./public/main.js",
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*"
    ],
    "win": {
      "target": "portable"
    }
  }
}
```

```
|---public
|     |---index.html
|     |---main.js
|---src
|     |---App.js
|     |---index.js
|     |...
```

main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require("url")

function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1600,
    height: 1200
  })

  win.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.resolve(__dirname, "./index.html"),
      protocol: "file",
      slashes: true
    })
  )
  win.webContents.openDevTools();
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow()
    }
  })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
```

If I have the localhost up and the pathname for main.js goes to `"http://localhost:3000"` everything works as intended, the React App renders.

When I have the pathname point to `path.resolve(__dirname, "./index.html")` it sees the html and renders it, but does not actually render any of the React App.

Answer (score 0):

[Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) can be used to achieve that, it is a React framework that uses webpack to export react as static files, without a server running in the background and with little configuration.
There is an example on its Github repository of how to use it with electron, which uses a web server during development and is exported as static files on production. [You can check the example here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-electron).

As you can see in the example, React is kept inside the `renderer` folder, while electron scripts are kept inside the `main` folder.

```
|--main/
|    |--main.js      // Your electron main process
|    |--preload.js
|--renderer/
|    |--components/  // Your React components
|    |--pages/
|         |--_app.js
|         |--index.js
|    |--public/
|    |--styles/
|    |--babel.config.js
|--package.json
```

When Next is exported as static files, it outputs the result to `renderer/out`, this folder will contain an html file for every js file that you had in `renderer/pages` excepting `_app.js`, which won't have its own html file and instead will be included in every page, if you want read more about `_app.js` [click here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app).

This is what the output might look like:

```
|--renderer/out
     |--_next/
     |--404.html
     |--index.html
```

If you added a file in `renderer/pages/welcome.js` when exported, the `renderer/out` folder would also have a `welcome.html` file.
With this, you can simply load the html file:

```js
win.loadFile('../renderer/out/index.html');
win.loadFile('../renderer/out/welcome.html');
```

If you want to use typescript there is also an example for that [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-electron-typescript).
And also [give a look to the next documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started).

If you don't want to use Next, there are also some boilerplates and examples that you might want to look at which use webpack:

- https://github.com/alexdevero/electron-react-webpack-boilerplate
- https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack-quick-start
- https://github.com/hamzaak/electron-react-webpack-boilerplate

Good luck!